# Programatically iterate all windows/views in an iOS application

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios

I'm a C++/Windows developer getting to grips with iOS AND OBJ-C... can anyone provide sample code how I could iterate through all windows/views belonging to my application and log/print to the debugger some vital information about the size, position, state, etc of each. I'm using a 3rd-party library and am not really understanding exactly what it is creating on my behalf.

Comment: How is this not a proper question? I asked a well defined question which clearly can have a proper, specific answer. I'm sure SO is way more trigger-happy on the close button than it used to be, and people far less likely to actually give helpful reasons _why_ they vote to close so one can actually learn how to fix the question.

Comment: There has been an increase in the number of questions that amount to `send me da codez` rather than people trying something and then asking a question as to why it went wrong.  Especially with things that could easily be answered by google. Your question could easily be  misconstrued to be of that type of question.

Comment: I think it's a proper question, users are way fast raising their antennas when an user asks how to do something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the debugger, you can try:

```
po [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
po [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]
```